# OpenAPI Request and Response Examples in .NET 6

Tags: openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, .net-6.0

Has anyone had success yet with getting complex Swagger Request and Response examples to render through the Swagger UI in .NET 6?

I'm on .NET 6 RC 1 trying to use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.2.1 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters 7.0.2. The [instructions](https://mattfrear.com/2016/01/25/generating-swagger-example-requests-with-swashbuckle/) say "Don’t forget to enable the ExamplesOperationFilter", but I can't even find the definition of `ExamplesOperationFilter`.  Where is it?

I have seen the XML `<example>` tag stuff, but that's too simple for my needs - I have nested arrays and lists and enums and all sorts of stuff I want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it going.  Didn't need `ExamplesOperationFilter`.

In Program.cs I needed:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblyOf<MySampleRequest>();
```

And in the controller I needed `[SwaggerRequestExample(...)]` for the request.  For the response, `[SwaggerResponse(Type=...)]` seemed to be enough.